# Could I buy Google Colab Pro with Google Play card or PayPal?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I wanna use Google Colab Pro for obtaining better RAM, but I have no credit card, only PayPal and Google Play cards. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Not a right place to ask such questions, but I get first timers may get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding another payment method in your google payment center